# Notepad++ 7.7.1 installed on Windows 7 Professional (and also on Windows 10) does not save the new files with selected extensions

Tags: notepad++, file-extension, save-as

I have installed notepad++ 7.7.1 version on Windows 7 Professional. When I am trying to save a newly created file (for example *ex1*) with any file extension - using **File -> Save As** option - despite selecting any extension from **Save as type**, the saved file has no extension to selected programming language. This means if I am trying to save the newly created file *ex1* either as .php or .py or .rb etc, all I am getting is the saved file as just ex1 (without any selected extension). Thus if I need to save this as a php file then I need to give the required extension name also along with the choose file name. Thus if I need to save ex1 as the PHP file then I need to type the file name as **ex1.php** OR if I want to save this new file as a Python file, then I need to give the file name as **ex1.py** etc.

I explored these links before posting this question - but am unable to identify and fix this issue:

https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/1129

https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/27926-file-extension-not-file-association-list.html

PS> Just before posting this question, I also installed **Atom 1.40.1 x64** - and here also, I am unable to select and add a desired file extension. This clearly indicates that something I am missing which is neither specific to notepad++ nor to Atom. Thanks a lot in advance to for the help!

Comment: Just wanted to add that I have installed Windows 7 as well as Windows 10 on two different laptops recently (OS reinstall - after OS crashed) - and then I have installed the latest versions of notepad++ on to them, and now encountering this problem. However, I have been using notepad++ on Windows 7 Professional earlier for many years and had never encountered such a weird problem.)

Comment: If it's *neither specific to notepad++ nor to Atom*, it would appear to be an OS issue, which means it's off-topic for SO. You should ask this question on [su] instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that showing the known file extension is the solution!

You will have to disable **Hide extensions for known file types** in **File explorer options** or **Folder options**.